# How to proxy an HTTP method with play framework 2.5?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have 2 simple APIs:

```
GET      /users/me/photos        controllers.api.UserController.getMyPhotos
GET      /users/:userId/photos   controllers.api.UserController.getPhotos(userId: Int)
```

Here's `getPhotos`:

```
def getPhotos(userId: Int) = SecuredAction.async {
  logger.info(s"Searching for user $userId's photos")

  userPhotosRepo.findByUserId(userId).map {
    photos => Ok(Json.toJson(photos))
  }
}
```

Here's `getMyPhotos`:

```
def getMyPhotos = SecuredAction.async { request =>

  request.identity.id.map { currentUserId =>
    logger.info(s"Searching for current user's photos")

    getPhotos(currentUserId) // doesn't work
  }.getOrElse(Future.successful(InternalServerError))
}
```

How can I make `getMyPhotos` proxy through to `getPhotos` without creating a helper method they both call?

Comment: What is the error returned ? I think that your code should work (the code in SecuredAction will be called twice, once for `getMyPhotos` and once for `getPhotos`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use reverse routing provided by Play Framework

```
 [full package].routes.[controller].[method]
```

In your case

```
routes.api.UserController.getPhotos(request.identity.id)
```

If you want the result of first action

```
val ans: Result = Redirect(routes.api.UserController.getPhotos(request.identity.id))
```

I hope that's what you were trying to ask.

EDIT:

For your concern this should be a proper way to do it

```
def getPhotos(userId: Long) = SecuredAction.async {
  userPhotosRepo findByUserId(userId) map {
    photos => Ok(Json.toJson(photos))
  }
}

def getMyPhotos = SecuredAction.async { request =>
   request.identity.id map { id =>
       Redirect(routes.HomeController.getPhotos(id))
  }
 }
```

Comment: I've just tried this but I get an error: `play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[Cannot write an instance of play.api.mvc.Result to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[play.api.mvc.Result]]`
My code is just `Future.successful(Ok(Redirect(routes.UserController.getPhotos(currentUserId))))`. I don't want to issue an actual HTTP redirect so I'm assuming this is just a transparent internal redirect?

Comment: Which action you want to call in another action?
-  I am assuming that you want to call getMyPhotos in getPhotos ? 
-  Do you want response from one action in another one?

Comment: No. `getMyPhotos` is the one that gets the current user's ID from their auth info. I then just want to return the result of calling `getPhotos(currentUserId)` from `getMyPhotos`. It's just a convenience method so the client doesn't need to know what the logged-in user's ID is.

Comment: If you want to achieve something like this go through my EDIT, this can be a better option and will add abstraction as you wanted.